# Confusion understanding closures

Tags: javascript, closures

Conceptually closures make a bit of sense to what's happening, but in practice, I have no idea what's going on. For the problem I am dealing with I want to count the occurrences of numbers I read in and store it in a histogram. This is supposed to happen in the countOccurences function, but the histogram array never gets updated.

```
var LinkedList = function() {
this.head = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val) {
  this.head = {data: val, next: this.head};
};

LinkedList.prototype.forEach = function(action) {
   for (var temp = this.head; temp; temp = temp.next) {
     action(temp.data);
   }   
 };
 // This is where the closure concept should take effect
 var countOccurrences = function(histogram) { 

     return function(val){ // Not working as expected, The val should equal 
                        // a number found in the list. Take for example if 
                        // 1 is found then histogram[1]++. Meaning we've  
                        // seen the number 1 once in the list so far. This
                        // continues until the entire list has been processed.
       histogram[val]++;
     }; 
  }

 function printHistogram(histogram) {
     for (var i in histogram) {
         if (histogram[i]) {
           println("(#" + i + ":" + histogram[i] +")")
         }   
     }
  }

var main = function() {
    var list = new LinkedList(); //Creates empty linkedlist
    var histogram = [];
    while (ln = readln().trim()) { //Reads in numbers from stdin
         list.add(ln)
    }   
    list.forEach(countOccurrences(histogram))
    printHistogram(histogram)
}; main()
```

Comment: The problem is countOccurrences function executes immediately and you are sending the data not the function reference (callback) to foreach function. Try to debug. You will understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: That "closure" is wrong, it does nothing. I am guessing you forgot a return? still not sure what it is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your closure is not actually returning a function. Not exactly sure how you are counting or what those values will be but you definitely need to start by returning your function from your closure.

```js
var LinkedList = function() {
  this.head = null;
}

LinkedList.prototype.add = function(val) {
  this.head = {
    data: val,
    next: this.head
  };
};

LinkedList.prototype.forEach = function(action) {
  for (var temp = this.head; temp; temp = temp.next) {
    action(temp.data);
  }
};
// This is where the closure concept should take effect
var countOccurrences = function(histogram) {

  return function(val) { // Not working as expected, I'm tring to get val to
    // be the data passed in from forEach which will 
    // then be incremeted accordingly in the histogram 
    // array
    histogram[val] = histogram[val] ? histogram[val] + 1 : 1;
  };
}

function printHistogram(histogram) {
  for (var i in histogram) {
    if (histogram[i]) {
      println("(#" + i + ":" + histogram[i] + ")")
    }
  }
}

var main = function() {
  var list = new LinkedList(); //Creates empty linkedlist
  var histogram = [];
  while (ln = readln().trim()) { //Reads in numbers from stdin
    list.add(ln)
  }
  list.forEach(countOccurrences(histogram))
  printHistogram(histogram)
};
main()
```

Comment: I added the return, but it isn't making a difference. And those values are supposed to work as follows. If I have a list with [1,3,4,5,1], the histogram will go to index 1 per say and increment its count, histogram[1]++ as such. So by the end of the function it will have a total of how many times an element has been seen.

Comment: I see. Fixed the code to initialize the count in the array if the value was not previously seen

Answer (score 0):

The actual closure was going wrong because of the lack of a return statement initially. However, after that, I found another bug that was unrelated to closure. The problem was in the function because I was incrementing a number that wasn't initialized. So the fix is as follows:

```
var countOccurrences = function(histogram) {

    return function(val) { 
       if(histogram[val])
          histogram[val]++;
       else
          histogram[val] = 1;
    };
   }
```

Regardless, much apperciation for the help.

Comment: You probably want to use an object for histogram. If you use an array you can have many empty values. eg if the first value added is 248, your histogram will be an array in length of 249 with mostly empty values.

Comment: Yea, that would probably be a better idea.